# How to show windows 7 boot screen through active directory

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

I am experiencing "temporary user profile" errors" on my corporate, "Windows 7 Professional" laptop. Instead of my regular home screen, it shows up as a "black screen".

After logging on through active directory, the computer goes through several different processes: user profiles and settings, group policy and Net-Motion policy, etc.

I know that there is a way to show boot logs through MSCONFIG.  I tried that but it only shows the drivers that are loaded.

I am trying to get a text file of the start-to-finish login.  I would like to know everything that happens after I enter my username and password...from which domain controller it uses, etc...all the way to the time when the desktop loads.

Is this possible and how?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Between the Event Viewer in compmgmt.msc and the bootlog via msconfig.exe you should have all the info you need. Eventviewer shows you all loaded services in "System", connections to your DC in "Security", etc. What´s more important, errors are highlighted and you get an EventID you can use to research your problem.